# What is the difference between variable and random variable?

Tags: regression, self-study, random-variable, descriptive-statistics

I know that "variable" means "values which vary." In a simple linear regression model :

$$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\epsilon$$

$X$ is variable that is the values of $X$ vary. Why is $X$ not a *random* variable? What is the difference between a variable and a random variable?

Comment: X is a random variable in this example. You might instead be thinking of the distinction between *fixed* and *random* effects? These are terms used  to describe the parameters being estimated. For example, $\beta_1$ could be thought of as a single value that is the same across observations, or as a random variable that can differ across observations.

Comment: @DLDahly, what about controlled experiments or dummy variables? Is $X$ a random variable even then?

Comment: For me, a random variable is something that can take different values across observations, and the term random doesn't really mean it needs to be randomly allocated. There might be some deeper philisophical nuance that other's might better understand.

Comment: Very roughly, random variable is a variable equipped with probability. In mathematics, you say $X$ is a variable if it is not fixed and can take multiple values. But does every possible value have the same chance (probability) of being selected? For example, if $X$ takes either 0 or 1 as its value, what can you say about the chance $X=1$ if $X$ is just a "variable"? If $X$ is a Bernoulli(p) "random variable", then you know $X=0$ with chance 1-p, and $X=1$ with chance p.

Comment: In regression, you can regard $X$ as a random variable if you know/assume its distribution, but it doesn't help because regression cares for only conditional distribution/expectation of $Y$ given $X$. That is, $X$ is fixed as a constant for the moment.

Comment: $Y$ is a random variable in regression, and $X$ variables are actually supposed to be experimentally controlled levels of a factor. But that's not what people commonly do - they simply throw age in as a predictor, and blood pressure as an outcome. At this point the regression model assumes that age level was an experimental level -- whereby the investigators said: "first, go out and get 45 year old subjects, measure blood pressure, done. Next, go out and get 46 year old subjects, measure pressure, done. Finally, run a regression of pressure on the experimental levels of age. You have to regres

Comment: What a random variable is has been discussed extensively at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50.  $X$ might or might not be a random variable in this model, depending on how you view its values as arising.

Answer (score 10):

A variable is a symbol that represents some quantity. A variable is useful in mathematics because you can prove something without assuming the value of a variable and hence make a general statement over a range of values for that variable.

A random variable is a value that follows some probability distribution. In other words, it's a value that is subject to some randomness or chance.

In linear regression, $X$ may be viewed either as a random variable that is observed or it can be considered as a predetermined fixed value which, as LEP already discussed, the investigator chooses. As you've pointed out, we usually assume the later (whether or not this assumption is correct is another story). However, the OLS estimator is unbiased whether or not you treat $X$ as random *and* the estimate of the variance of the OLS estimator is unbiased for the variance of $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$ whether or not you treat $X$ as random. These are a couple reasons people don't get too caught up in whether or not to assume $X$ is random in regression.

If you treat $X$ as random, I will show that the OLS estimator is still unbiased below.

Let $X$ be a random variable and let $\hat{\beta}_{OLS} = (X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} Y$.

$E(\hat{\beta}_{OLS})=E[E[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|X]]=E[E[(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T} Y|X]]=E[(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T}E[ Y|X]] =E[(X^{T}X)^{-1} X^{T}X\beta] =E[\beta]=\beta$

If you treat $X$ as random, I will show that the estimate of the variance of $\hat{\beta}_{OLS}$ is unbiased for the unconditional variance below.

$Var(\hat{\beta}_{OLS})=Var(E(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|X)) + E(Var(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}| X))=Var(\beta)+ E(Var(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|X))=E(Var(\hat{\beta}_{OLS}|X))=E(\sigma^{2}( X^{T} X)^{-1})$

Answer (score 7):

When you wrote down your equation, you did not list the assumptions: $$Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\epsilon$$

> Why is X not a random variable?

Yes, it is often assumed (for simplicity of exposition in the intro statistics textbooks) that $X$ is fixed, or as you put it *non-random*.

It is fixed (non-random) in controlled experiments, i.e. mostly in natural sciences such as physics and biology. You can set the parameter $X$ at the level you're interested, and measure the response $Y$. In this case you make a set of assumptions such as [Gauss-Markov theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem). For instance, feed the mice 1 mg of ascorbic acid and measure their hair loss. You control how much of the substance to administer.

However, it can be random, and it usually $is$ random in *observational* studies, i.e. 99% of all economics and social sciences alike. I can't set Dow-Jones Index (DJIA) at the arbitrary level, and measure the response in GDP (gross domestic product). I can only *observe* both, and whatever it is DJIA the day of my observation, that's my $X$. That's why the $X$ *is random*. In this case I have to use a different set of assumptions than the controlled experiment above. Imagine, now how difficult it is to establish causality between DJIA and DGP, unlike the case with mice when I decided how much of what to feed.

Here's additional reading:

- The Gauss-Markov Theorem and Random Regressors. Author(s): Juliet Popper Shaffer. The American Statistician, Vol. 45, No. 4 (Nov., 1991), pp. 269-273
- "Gauss–Markov Assumptions for Observational Research (Arbitrary x)" in [Encyclopedia of Research Design](https://books.google.com/books?id=b_1yAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA532&ots=VJ5TKVqA7-&dq=Gauss%E2%80%93Markov%20Assumptions%20for%20Observational%20Research%20(Arbitrary%20x)&pg=PA531#v=twopage&q&f=false), p.532:

> A parallel but stricter set of Gauss–Markov
>   assumptions is typically applied in practice in the
>   case of observational data, where the researcher
>   cannot assume that x is fixed in repeated samples.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking the **outcomes of an experiment (experiment = a random procedure)** can be numerical (i.e rolling a die) or can be mapped to numbers by the designer (i.e flipping a coin, with outcomes 1=head and 0=tail).

This **numerical representation of the outcomes** defines the **random variables**.

In these examples, we can tell that there is some **chance involved**, in other words we don't control the experiment 100%. So a random variable is linked to observations in the real world, where **uncertainty is involved**, and that's where the "randomness" comes from.

Most importantly, as others have already pointed out, a random variable *x* (which is either **discrete** or **continuous**) is quantified by a **probability density function (pdf)**. So we say that, **random variables** have **distributions**.

Now, in the case of linear regression, you **ALREADY** know the values of **X** and from that you try to figure out the values of **Y**, in other words, **Y** is the random variable (as you still don't have its values and they will depend on **X**s' values).

Resources:

[1] [Can someone help to explain the difference between independent and random?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231425/can-someone-help-to-explain-the-difference-between-independent-and-random)

[2] https://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic4/4_md/SeniorTopic4c.html

[3] [Independent variable = Random variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246047/independent-variable-random-variable)

Comment: Actually, if we're referring specifically to the OLS estimator, one of the assumptions is that the independent variables should be deterministic and not stochastic.