# Derivative of matrix w.r.t vector

Tags: matrix, gradient-descent, derivative, gradient, matrix-calculus

I'm quite out of my element trying to do some matrix calculus.

I would like to know what the derivative of $z^{T}y$ w.r.t $z$ is, where z, y are n length vectors.

Can anyone suggest good resources as well?

Thank you!

Comment: The derivative with respect to $z$ implies calculating the derivative in each component of $z$. for example, the derivative in component $z_1$ is $y_1$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: So since $z^{T}y$ is a n by n matrix do I calculate the derivative of each element w.r.t each element in $z$?

Comment: $z^Ty$ is a scalar. $z$ is a vector (well, also a $n\times 1$ matrix).

Comment: I recently posted a thorough discussion of such derivatives at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/257616/919.  Because the the map $z\to z^\prime y$ is linear, *it is its own derivative*: it linearly approximates itself.  Our site has several threads on resources about matrix calculations: see http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=matrix+cookbook.