# What is the derivative of $\|X^T-S^TAX^T\|_F^2$ w.r.t $A$?

Tags: matrix, derivative, matrix-calculus

What is the derivative of $F = \|X^T-S^TAX^T\|_F^2$   w.r.t $A$,
where $X \in\mathbb R^{d \times N}$, $S \in\mathbb R^{k \times N}$, and $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times N}$?

I have tried, and it is as follows:

$$\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial A} = -(X^T-S^TAX^T)SX$$

but I think the result is not correct, because the dimensions do not match. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be squaring the matrix $X^T - S^TAX^T$, but you shouldn't.  Just take its derivative, note that for $F = ||B||_F^2$, $dF/db_{ij} = 2b_{ij}$, and the path to the result should be clear..

Comment: Because your function is very nearly the same as the one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/257579 (assuming "$_F$" refers to the Frobenius norm), surely the methods described in my answer there will readily apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From section 2.5.2 of [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathrm X}\text{Tr}\left[(\mathrm A \mathrm X \mathrm B + \mathrm C)( \mathrm A \mathrm X \mathrm B + \mathrm C)^\top\right]=2 \mathrm A^\top( \mathrm A \mathrm X \mathrm B + \mathrm C) \mathrm B^\top
$$

Hence,

$$\nabla_{\mathrm A} \| \mathrm X^{\top} - \mathrm S^{\top} \mathrm A \mathrm X^{\top} \|_{\rm F}^2 = \nabla_{\mathrm A} \| \mathrm S^{\top} \mathrm A \mathrm X^{\top} - \mathrm X^{\top} \|_{\rm F}^2 = 2 \, \mathrm S \left( \mathrm S^{\top} \mathrm A \mathrm X^{\top} - \mathrm X^{\top} \right) \mathrm X$$

Answer (score 3):

We have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\|X^T - S^TAX^T \| & = \text{Tr}(X^T - S^TAX^T)^T(X^T - S^TAX^T) \\
 & = \text{Tr}(X - (S^TAX^T)^T)(X^T - S^TAX^T) \\
 & = \text{Tr}(XX^T - XS^TAX^T -(S^TAX^T)^TX^T + (S^TAX^T)^T(S^TAX^T))\\
 & = \text{Tr}(XX^T) - 2\text{tr}(XS^TAX^T) + \text{tr}(XA^TSS^TAX^T))\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Then,

It is clear that

$$ \frac{\partial \text{Tr}(XX^T)}{\partial A} = 0. $$

For the second term we have :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial (2\text{tr}(XS^TAX^T))}{\partial A} & = \frac{\partial (2\text{Tr}(X^TXS^TA))}{\partial A} \\
& = 2(X^TXS^T)^T \\
& = 2SX^TX. \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Here, we used formula 100 of the [TheMatrixCookBook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf): $\frac{\partial \text{Tr}(AX)}{\partial X} = A^T$

For the last term we have (formula 116 of the [TheMatrixCookBook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/edoc/imm3274.pdf)):
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial \text{Tr}(XA^TSS^TAX^T))}{\partial A} & = SS^TAX^TX + SS^TAX^TX \\
& = 2SS^TAX^TX \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Putting all together we obtain:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial \|X^T - S^TAX^T \| }{\partial A} & =  2SS^TAX^TX - 2SX^TX\\
& = 2S(S^TAX^T - X^T)X \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}