# What's wrong with this conditional probability working?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

A past exam paper for my course (BSc Mathematics, second-year module in statistical inference and modelling, unpublished) has a question,

> Let $(X,Y)^T$ be a bivariate random variable with joint probability density function $$
> f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{5}(x+2y) && \text{if }x\in[0,1],\;y\in[0,2], \\
> 0 && \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
> Find $\mathbb{E}(Y|X=x)$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

So far I have the following working.
\begin{align}
& \begin{aligned}
f_X(x)
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) \; \text{d}y && (1) \\
& = \int_0^2 \frac{1}{5}(x+2y) \; \text{d}y && (2) \\
& = \left[\frac{1}{5}(xy+y^2)\right]_{y=0}^2 && (3) \\
& = \frac{1}{5}(2x+4) && (4)
\end{aligned} \\
\therefore \; & \begin{aligned}[t]
f_{Y|X=x}(y)
& = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_X(x)} && (5) \\
& = \frac{\frac{1}{5}(x+2y)}{\frac{1}{5}(2x+4)} && (6) \\
& = \frac{x+2y}{2x+4} && (7)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
which is not a function of only $y$. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You calculated the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ - it *should* depend on $x$

Comment: @J.Delaney My course notes define conditional probability (in a bivariate context) as a function of a single variable, namely the one appearing before the "given" bar. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You misunderstood something. Think about what *"given $x$"* means

Comment: @J.Delaney I understand it to mean "Fix an $x$, so that $x$ is no longer a variable".

Comment: ... and where, in relationship to the "given" bar, is the only variable left that is actually a variable, given that $x$ no longer is?

Comment: Indeed if you will *fix* $x$ to some value (e.g. $x$=1) then your result will no longer depend on $x$

Comment: @jbowman Before it. I'm not sure I get your drift.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/392168/conditional-expectation-function

Comment: @J.Delaney OK, I think I get that. So for a given $x$, $x$ is a constant.