# Why is the likelihood function for linear regression based on $(|)$ instead of $(,)$

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood

Likelihood functions typically based on the joint probabilities of the variables involved. In linear regression we have variables  and , but derivations for MLE under a zero meaned gaussian assumption for the errors uses the conditional probability (|) for the likelihood function. Why does this deviate from the standard of usage of joint probability (,)?

Comment: Models have a regression structure if the predictor or explanatory variables 
either are design variables, (variables subject to experimental control) or are 
ancillary (variables that have a joint marginal distribution that does not 
depend on model parameters). With this type of structure, the analysis can 
be made conditional on the explanatory variables, and it is customary to do 
so.

Comment: @JesperforPresident Hmm I see. So then why for gaussian discriminant analysis do we use the joint probability instead of the conditional?

Comment: I am not expert on LDA, but from what I understand the explanatory variables are not ancillary for LDA.

Comment: @David, can you provide a reference for LDA? My understanding is that, for LDA, we also classify variables $y$ depending on predictors $x$. E.g., the choice of travel mode *given*, say, age, gender, income.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Sure. I saw it in these notes: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf, pg 5 towards the bottom. Note that I'm not well versed with MLE, but it looks like the joint probability is used to me.

Comment: Hm, which part of these notes do you refer to? E.g., "we can then use the Gaussian Discriminant Analysis (GDA) model, which models p(x|y)" looks pretty conditional to me?

Comment: @ChristophHanck, the second to last equation from the bottom of page 5 writes the likelihood in terms of the product of the joint distributions. When MLE is performed for regression under zero meaned gaussian assumption, they wrote it as the product of the conditional distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p(y,x)=p_1(y|x)p_2(x)$ from the definition of conditional density, the log likelihood is given by $\log p(y,x)=\log p_1(y|x) + \log p_2(x)$. However, since $\log p_2(x)$ does not depend on the parameter of interest, $\beta$ and $\sigma^2$, maximizing $\log p_1(y|x)$ is equivalent to maximizing $\log p(y,x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Regression models are models for **conditional expectations**. Linear regression is then a model for the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X=x$. So $x$, the realized value, is usually treated as a known value, without uncertainty (if that is not your case, look for *errors in variables*).

You can find much more information in this other posts:

- [Independent variable = Random variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246047/independent-variable-random-variable/246388#246388)
- [What is the difference between conditioning on regressors vs. treating them as fixed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144826/what-is-the-difference-between-conditioning-on-regressors-vs-treating-them-as-f/192746#192746)
- [What are the differences between stochastic and fixed regressors in linear regression model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215230/what-are-the-differences-between-stochastic-and-fixed-regressors-in-linear-regre/417324#417324)