# How to derive a regularized machine learning objective function with the maximum a posteriori for random features?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, regularization, posterior

My question is at the end of the post. I tried to give as much information as I can to clarify my understanding and to point out as precisely as possible where I am stuck.

#### Independent variables or features may be fixed or random

I have recently read that when performing a regression, the independent variables or features may be fixed or random [[Independent variable = Random variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246047/independent-variable-random-variable)], like for instance for the linear regression where "the values $x_{ij}$ may be viewed as either observed values of random variables $Xj$ or as fixed values chosen prior to observing the dependent variable" [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression].

#### Regularization and prior distribution

Besides, I know that the regularization in machine learning objective function corresponds to a prior knowledge on the parameter. For instance, the L2 regularization assumes that the parameters follow a centered Normal distribution and the L1 regularization assumes that the parameters follow a Laplace distribution. **For me, this is clear when the independent variables are fixed but I have trouble to understand this when they are random variables.**

#### 1. Fixed independent variables case

When the independent variables are fixed, we model the dependent variable with a chosen distribution. For instance, for the linear regression, we use the following model:
$$Y\sim\mathcal{N}(X\beta,\sigma^{2}I)$$

##### Frequentist approach

In the frequentist approach, $\hat{\beta}$ can then be obtained be maximizing the likelihood:
$$\hat{\beta}=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}(f_Y(y))$$

##### Bayesian approach

When considering a prior Normal distribution on $\beta$ for instance, the previous model changes into:
$$Y|\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(X\beta,\sigma^{2}I)$$
$$\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}_{\beta}I_{\beta})$$
In this case, $\hat{\beta}$ can then be obtained be maximizing the maximum a posteriori:
$$\hat{\beta}=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}(f_{\beta|Y}(\beta|y))$$
Thanks to Bayes' theorem, $f_{\beta|Y}(\beta|y)=\frac{f_{Y|\beta}(y|\beta)f_{\beta}(\beta)}{f_{Y}(y)}$, we can then obtain $\hat{\beta}$ be maximizing the following quantity (since the denominator does not depend on $\beta$), which corresponds to a machine learning objective function including a regularization term:
$$\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}&=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}(f_{Y|\beta}(y|\beta)f_{\beta}(\beta))\\
&=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmin}}(-log(f_{Y|\beta}(y|\beta)) -log(f_{\beta}(\beta)))
\end{align}$$

#### 2. Random independent variables case

When the independent variables are random variables, the previous model changes to:
$$Y|X,\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(X\beta,\sigma^{2}I)$$
$$\beta\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^{2}_{\beta}I_{\beta})$$
Like previously, $\hat{\beta}$ can then be obtained be maximizing the maximum a posteriori:
$$\hat{\beta}=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}(f_{\beta|Y,X}(\beta|y,x))$$
I think that the desired result should be the following to get the same objective function as previously, including the regularization term (unless I am wrong):
$$\begin{align}
\hat{\beta}&=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}(f_{\beta|Y,X}(\beta|y,x))\\
&=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmax}}(f_{Y|\beta,X}(y|\beta,x)f_{\beta}(\beta))\\
&=\underset{\beta}{\mathrm{argmin}}(-log(f_{Y|\beta,X}(y|\beta,x))-log(f_{\beta}(\beta)))
\end{align}$$
If so, I cannot find out why. In particular, I don't know why the first and second lines are equal. Thanks to Bayes' theorem, I know that:
$$\begin{align}
f_{\beta|Y,X}(\beta|y,x)&=\frac{f_{\beta,Y,X}(\beta,y,x)}{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}\\&=\frac{f_{Y|\beta,X}(y|\beta,x)f_{\beta,X}(\beta,x)}{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}\\&=\frac{f_{Y|\beta,X}(y|\beta,x)f_{X|\beta}(x|\beta)f_{\beta}(\beta)}{f_{Y,X}(y,x)}
\end{align}$$
But I am stuck there. I could find the desired result if $X$ and $\beta$ are independent (I don't know whether this is true, an assumption of the model ...).

Could someone help me understand the maximum a posteriori/regularization when the independent variables / features are random variables? Can the previous formula be simplified? If so, why?

Comment: Could you change the title to something that better reflects the actual question?

Comment: The expression for the posterior of $\beta$ given $X,Y$ you wrote seems to be correct - why do you think it should equal $p(y|\beta,X) p(\beta)$ ? this has no meaning.  Also note that your notation is redundant, there is not need to write the conditional dependencies both as a subscript and as the function argument, It is conventional to simply write e.g. $p(y|\beta,X)$

Comment: Regarding the notation, I stick to the courses I followed in my academic background.

Comment: Regarding the result, I assume this is the desired result by comparing to machine learning objective function. Indeed, when using regularization, the objective function includes two terms: the traditional cost to minimize $-log(f_{Y|\beta,X}(y|\beta,x))$ and the regularization term $-log(f_{\beta}(\beta))$. I will edit the post to clarify the reason of my expectation.